# Is it possible to replace a two way switch with two wall PIR sensors?

Tags: switches, wiring, light-sensor

I have a two-way switch for the lights on the staircase and I want to replace them with two-PIR sensors.

I received the sensors yesterday and I discovered that they have only two wires and I am wondering if I will be able to connect the wires to make them work. By having them working I do expect that any of the two sensors to be able to open the lights (close the circuit).

Probably my current configuration is like this:
[image]

How do I need to do the rewiring?

Answer (score 3):

Easily done:

3-Wire Sensor

[image]

2-Wire Sensor

[image]

Comment: When the PIR lets current pass, not only the main lamp but also the additional ones turn on. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Exactly the same as the switch, so this is expected operation.

Comment: Yeah, but say I wanted to turn on the additional lamps with the switch only. Is it a possible circuit or do you think I'd be better off using a relay instead?

Comment: @aksu  That is a different question than that posed above. And yes, relays would be the way to achieve it.